# Nodejs proxy post datas from backend,and angularjs post data errors 415，unsupported Media Type

Tags: angularjs

I am a new angular/nodejs learner from China,and I have problems here confused me a lot after searching loads of answers in stackoverflow,nodejs what I am using is cors-proxy https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy, confustions as follows：
http://example-pc:1337 is cors-proxy while “api.server.com:80/server/src/order/datas” is a interface posted from backend.post data by angularjs errors 415 unsupported Media Type

```
$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function(pageSize, page, searchText) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  var data;
  var url = 'http://example-pc:1337/api.server.com:80/server/src/order';
 if (searchText) {
       var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
       $http.post(url).success(function(largeLoad) {
       data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
         returnJSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1; });
       $scope.setPagingData(data, page, pageSize);});
     } else {
            $http.post(url)
            //'../data/prots' + $stateParams.proType + '.json'
                .success(function(largeLoad) {
                    $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad, page, pageSize);
            });
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

corsproxy

```
 response.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = request.headers.origin
 response.headers['access-control-allow-headers']=allowedHeaders.join(', ')
 response.headers['access-control-expose-headers'] = 'Content- Type,content-length, etag'
 response.headers['access-control-allow-methods'] = 'GET, PUT, POST,   DELETE'
 response.headers['access-control-allow-credentials'] = 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the problems and finally get my problems resolved,I would like to provide my solution to this issue,I hope it's helpful to get your problems resolved.

```
$http(
               {method:'POST',
                 url,
                data: {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
                data: { 'Id': '11' }
               }).success(function(largeLoad)...
...
```

Add data: {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'},
    data: { 'Id': '11' } in my code,then the problem disappeared.
Thank you!